# PHP : using multiple forms in a page

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql, forms

i've a situation where i've to show  forms  just like  excel sheet and then against each row there is a submit button ,Once submit button is  clicked data  is saved against that row , row is disabled and focus is set to next line  automatically 
see my screenshot what i've 
[image]

i'm creating form using this code

```
<table border="1" cellspacing="5">
   <?php  
   for ($index = 0; $index <4; $index++) {
        echo "<form method='post' action='' id='myform'>";
            echo"<tr>";
            echo"<td><input type='text' name='name$index'></td>";
            echo"<td><input type='text' name='email$index'></td>";
            echo"<td><input type='submit' name='submit$index'></td>";
            echo"</tr>";
        echo "</form>";
    }
   ?>
</table>
```

when i enter data in first form i'm able to get it and save in database but i really not getting how can i go to second line and then process it , please help me about it as i am new and  not sure if i am using right approach to do it

Comment: provide your js code .. but 1st  id must be unique so use class='myform' instead of id='myform'

Comment: You should not nest a `<form>` tag between `<table>` and `<tr>` tags like that, browsers might not render it correctly.

Comment: Have you ever heard of Ajax? Your question is asking us to read your mind, but I am up to the challenge. You're really asking how you can submit one form after another without refreshing the page, right?  Ajax.

Comment: @developerwjk its not about refreshing page or not , all that i  mean using forms like i mentioned above i can capture values in $_post array for first submit , how  can i  move to  second line after i did submit first one ? hope its clear

Comment: is `echo "<form method='post' action='' id='myform' target='_blank'>";` what you're looking for?

Comment: @developerwjk  see , i've 3 forms in  1 table . when i submit first button i recieve its vealues here  if(isset($_POST[]) , now what i want when first form is submitted  i control moves to second  form automatically  that is in second line and so on  , hope you get my point now

Comment: Doesn't the page refresh between submits? Would that not preclude your ability to move automatically to the next? Not seeing why you said the page refresh is not your problem.

Comment: if you please check my edited comment , how can i move to next  line when first  form is submitted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should assign to your submit button for each row the same name and  a value related to the id eg: the index

```
  <table border="1" cellspacing="5">
   <?php  
   for ($index = 0; $index <4; $index++) {
        echo "<form method='post' action='' id='myform'>";
            echo"<tr>";
            echo"<td><input type='text' name='name$index'></td>";
            echo"<td><input type='text' name='email$index'></td>";
            echo"<td><input type='submit' name='my_action' value="$index"></td>";
            echo"</tr>";
        echo "</form>";
    }
   ?>
</table>
```

In your Server myRelatedAction.php  you can easily obtain the index submitted

```
 $my_index = $_POST['my_action'] ;
```

Comment: can u please explain  a bit more ?

Comment: Yes. what do you don't understand?

Comment: this is how i  recieve values , if(isset($_POST["submit"])){        
        
       $name= $_POST["name"]; 
       $email= $_POST["email"];}  so how do i relate it with your answer please if i want to move to next line when i have recieved first form values

Comment: In my answer every time you press a submit button obviously the data are submitted to the server and in the server you can get in $name the value of index. The name is always the same so you can read teh $_POST otherwise you raise an error accessing to a wrong name. The value contained in $_POST['my_action'] is equal to the value you assigned at value alias $index you can use this value for you server action of for lead you response.  .

Comment: For the second line you can render the table with the value of the first and line and wait for the submit of the second. and so on for the third ... fourth ..

Comment: Othervise you should use ajax not using a submit button but a button calling a js function that perform an ajax (post) call to server sending the data and receiving the answer for the server . and finally preocessing this answer for new row..